# My page design getting distorted during page load and gets okay after pageload

Tags: jquery, html, css, autopostback, updatepanel-progressbar

Hi every Tech geek avilable in this forum
I am using the following code and i am using update panel
The issue is that i am using jquery for the alignment of the tabs used in my page
but when ever the page gets loaded the tabs gets distorted and looks as the initial stage li element and are un aligned
This is happening as i have used few service which call some otehr serices for data and it takes 1-2 seconds so in that timne frame the page looks distorted and as i know the jquery which is used to keep align the tabs is called after the whole html is loaded and code behind is executed
kindly help

```
<script src="/_layouts/1033/STYLES/js/commonstyles/js/jquery.uniform.js" type="text/javascript"
charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/1033/STYLES/js/commonstyles/js/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"
charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you including both the original and minified version?

Comment: Keep it hidden initially and later show it.

Comment: this is where the overlays and loading indicators come in… :p

Comment: keeping it hidden initially and showing latar on will not solve the problem as soon as the page will complete loading all the tabs will displayed at once which is not a good designing practice